# how to adapt N images inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with like 20 small images that are inline and I need to resize them if the user changes the screen width, now when there is no more free space on the right the last image of the row goes in the next line instead I want every image to resize. My structure is the following:

Example on the [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ae6y3dum/).

```css
.finitures {margin: 0;border-bottom: 1px solid #9c9b9b;padding-bottom: 20px;}
.finitures:last-child{border-bottom: none;}
.finiture-img img{border: 1px solid #898886; margin-top:2px; cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
 <div class="box-detail">
    <h1>Colori</h1>
    <div class="finitures">
        <div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div>
        <div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div><div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div><div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div><div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div><div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div><div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div><div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div><div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div><div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div><div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div><div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div><div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div><div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div><div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div><div class="finiture-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
        </div>
    </div>
```

how can I do it?

Comment: Try to learn some CSS or how to use search function on SO. You can try `width: 100%`  and `height: auto`

Comment: Use img{ max-width: 100%;}

Comment: I'm not really clear, I put your code in a jsfiddle and I have only 1 image per line (even in fullscreen), how many image there should be in 1 line?

Comment: when images are inline like this width:100% and height:auto doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a percentage width for image containers (`finiture-img`), plus setting a 100% width for images contained inside them. For example, if you have N=4, you can set `finiture-img` width to 25%.

```
.finiture-img
{
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:-4px;
    width:25%;
}

.finiture-img img
{
    border: 1px solid #898886; 
    margin-top:2px; 
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100%;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/czssvg3p/)

This allows you to scale images according to user screen width.

Please note both the `box-sizing:border-box` and the `margin-right:-4px` which allows you to eliminate space between `finiture-img` divs and scale them with a precise width even if they have border and paddings (you may find more info about box-sizing property [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)).

Answer (score 0):

Try with giving width of your image in `%`

```css
.finitures {margin: 0;border-bottom: 1px solid #9c9b9b;padding-bottom: 20px;}
.finitures:last-child{border-bottom: none;}
.finiture-img{display:inline;}
.finiture-img img{border: 1px solid #898886; margin-top:2px; cursor:pointer; width:25%;}
```

```html
<div class="box-detail">
                        <h1>Colori</h1>
                        <div class="finitures">
                            <div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div>
                            <div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div><div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div><div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div><div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div><div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div><div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div><div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div><div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div><div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div><div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div><div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div><div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div><div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div><div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div><div class="finiture-img">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/68x50/990000/fff">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```